# Why do these subqueries work separately, but not when using UNION?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The queries below both work on their own, but not when joined by a Union clause. Instead of listing the most recent 4 dates and those same 4 dates last year, it returns the most recent 4 dates and then the oldest 4 dates in the table.

Query 1

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 [Week Ending]
FROM [DataFormat]
ORDER BY [Week Ending] DESC;
```

Query 2

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 [Week Ending]
FROM [DataFormat]
WHERE [Week Ending] < DateAdd('yyyy',-1,(SELECT MAX([Week Ending]) FROM [DataFormat]))
ORDER BY [Week Ending] DESC;
```

This is the query that does not work:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 [Week Ending]
FROM [DataFormat]
ORDER BY [Week Ending] DESC;
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 [Week Ending]
FROM [DataFormat]
WHERE [Week Ending] < DateAdd('yyyy',-1,(SELECT MAX([Week Ending]) FROM [DataFormat]))
ORDER BY [Week Ending] DESC;
```

I want a column with the most recent `n` dates and those same dates 1 year ago.

Comment: It's ms-access. Don't ask too much of it.

Comment: Week ending dates would not be the same every year. So what you really want is the TOP 4 dates for each year, which won't necessarily be the same dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individual SELECTs making up a UNION are not allowed to contain an ORDER BY clause. The only ORDER BY clause allowed is at the end of the UNION and it applies to the entire UNION dataset. The first SELECT returns TOP 4 of an ascending set because the ORDER BY is ignored. The second SELECT returns TOP 4 records of an ascending dataset restricted by WHERE clause, again ORDER BY is not a factor in that selection. The 8 records are then sorted descending.

Save the two SELECT queries so ordering and TOP 4 selection takes place outside UNION. Build a UNION query with those two query objects.

```
SELECT Query1.* FROM Query1
UNION
SELECT Query2.* FROM Query2;
```

Comment: +1. It is explained in the documentation (mainly written by me): [Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1F772EC0-CC73-474D-AB10-AD0A75541C6E): _The last part of this SQL statement determines the ordering of the combined records by using an ORDER BY statement._ Thus, any preceeding ORDER BY clause is ignored, which will make the TOP n selections unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Week Ending]
FROM [DataFormat]
WHERE [Week Ending] IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 [Week Ending]
                        FROM [DataFormat]
                        ORDER BY [Week Ending] DESC
                       ) OR
      [Week Ending] IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 [Week Ending]
                        FROM [DataFormat]
                        WHERE [Week Ending] < DateAdd('yyyy', -1, (SELECT MAX([Week Ending]) FROM [DataFormat])
                       )
ORDER BY [Week Ending] DESC;
```

An index on `[Week Ending]` might help performance.

Comment: This just gives a syntax error, and access highlights the entire statement (super helpful debugging from M$). I suspect it has to do with the subqueries after each IN, but this does not work in Access.

Comment: After fixing the syntax here it, I let this run for 15 minutes (300k rows in this table) and it didn't finish executing.

Comment: @ChrisSardegna , try to use UNION ALL , probably will get such performance on it

Comment: I did use `UNION ALL` in my original query, but this answer doesn't use `UNION` at all.

Comment: I tested a nested query like this and it does work in Access.